# Sql server and Excel float to date offset

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime, type-conversion

I'm working with date and float conversion on sql server and excel.

This is my query:

```
select getdate(),convert(float, getdate())
```

I get:

```
2014-11-21 16:38:49.973     41962,6936339506
```

If I copy this float number to Excel and I change cell type as date I get this value:

```
19-nov-2014
```

What's that? Why there is an offest of two days?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13722614/1692632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server simply calculates the conversion of a date time to a float as the number of days since midnight on 01-Jan-1900 (i.e. `select convert(DATETIME, 0)` gives `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`)

Excel calculates a similar number, but the zero date is "00/01/1900". This is probably related to the fact that excel uses one based indexing, rather than the more common zero based indexing. The second day of difference comes from a [well known bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326) whereby excel considers 1900 to have been a leap year.

Takeaway message: if you assume that excel is always behind by two days you'll be ok, except for dates on or before the 28th of February 1900.

Comment: so are you saying that you can't properly import dates from excel into SQL Server, is there any workaround?

Comment: Workaround is as posted. Add two days for dates after 1900 and one day for dates before 1900 (if you have any). I am not aware of a cleaner fix.