# Days between two dates. Where is the error in dates'?

Tags: java, date, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the counts of days between two dates.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;
        String str1 = "01.01.1900";
        String str2 = "16.06.2017";
        try{
            date1 = format.parse(str1);
            date2 = format.parse(str2);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long i1 = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        System.out.println(i1/86400000);//milisec to days
    }
}
```

The result is: 42899 days.

BUT if we recheck that subtraction in EXCEL, the result is 42901 
[image]

Please, can anybody explain me where is the truth result?

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` class.  You should instead look in the `java.time` package and find the class most appropriate for your use case (probably `LocalDate` in this case).

Comment: You should test your code using closer dates, for example `01.01.1900` and `02.01.1900`. Maybe then you find where is the problem (or maybe Excel count something different than you).

Comment: the same 2 days difference

Comment: my tests' results :
01.01.2017 - 16.06.2017 = (java: 165) (excel: 166 )
but  01.06.2017 - 16.06.2017 = (java: 15) (excel: 15 )

Comment: Your assumption that each day has `86400000` milliseconds is a simplification; this does not take into account daylight savings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java round the result down when dividing integer numbers, so I think you have lost a day here:

```
System.out.println(i1/86400000);//milisec to days
```

After I tried **Java 8 API** it shows me **42900 days** (note that neither Java 8 nor Excel don't include the last day in the range):

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.of(1900, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate to = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 16);
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);
```

Another day was calculated by Excel in a wrong way due to a bug as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722566/is-there-a-bug-in-excel-concerning-dates).
So answering your question - **you loose one day on rounding and another day was incorrectly added by Excel**.

Comment: Incorrect. Excel doesn't include the end date either. Problem is in Excel, which incorrectly thinks that 1900 is a leap year. It is not. See: [Is there a bug in Excel concerning dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13722566/5221149) --- You are however correct about the rounding issue, but you don't explain *why* there is a rounding issue, i.e. that it is caused by the loss of an hours when switching to Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing this out - I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time). It has a better API that what's available in Java's standart library. Here is my code for your case:

```
package com.example;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // calculate  days between two dates 
    int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();

    System.out.println("Days = " + days);
 }
}
```

And the result is `Days = 42900`

Comment: Why do you call `minusDays(1)`? Is that just to artificially get the same *incorrect* result as Excel?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for that. I feel I have been a little remiss. Thank you for comment! I'll fix the code)

Comment: Joda-Time is in maintenance state, the official Joda-Time recommendation is you migrate to `java.time`. Still a better choice than the long outdated `java.util.Date`, though.