# VBA Excel: Did I find a bug with how Excel handles the "leap year" in 1900? (It wasn't actually leap year)

Tags: vba, excel

Disclaimer: This is a fairly specific bug I think I ran into in Excel but it's weird enough that I'll never find an answer to fix it, if it's even possible, if I don't post it here. It is an interesting one though so bear with me.

So a little context, I wrote some code that lets me capture a time stamp in column A when I input into column B. That works fine. I added a bit so it prompts the user if they are sure they want to change an entry after it has been entered, to keep the integrity of the time stamp. This also works.

During testing I ran into an issue, however. If I simply type a number into col A, the number 5 for example, it forces it into the format 1/5/1900 00:00. Makes sense to me, as Excel clearly chose 1900 as an arbitrary starting point. But if I try to edit this date, the prompt asking me if I want to change it shows up as 1/4/1900 (screenshot below). For the longest time I couldn't figure out why it was off by 1. I realized that any input between 1 and 60 (dates jan 1 to feb 29) caused this problem. Any dates after 3/1/1900 prompted me correctly. I did some digging and I found that the year 1900 doesn't have a leap year, so the number 60 should resolve to 3/1/1900 but instead goes to 2/29/1900 in Excel.

I know it's a small issue and only affects 60 possible entries in column A, but I feel helpless to fix it as it seems that the problem is how Excel calculates the leap year in 1900 when it shouldn't. Does anyone have a workaround, or at least a confirmation that this is a problem with Excel and not my code?

[Screenshot of 3 cases of editing column A.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVTet.png)

The 1st and 3rd results are expected. The middle one shows that even though the previous field was actually Jan 5, the prompt shows up as Jan 4. I'll post the code I have below in case anyone wants to try the same thing.

```
Private lastVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim timeCol, taskCol As Integer
Dim sRow, sCol As Integer
Dim currentCell As Range

timeCol = 1
taskCol = 2

sRow = Target.row
sCol = Target.Column

Set currentCell = Cells(sRow, sCol)

'Checks for timestamp or task column. If Cell wasn't empty, prompt user to 
'confirm the change
If sCol = timeCol Or sCol = taskCol Then
    If lastVal <> "" Then

        response = MsgBox("Old Value:  " & lastVal & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                & "New Value:  " & Cells(sRow, sCol) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                & "Are you sure you want to make this change?", _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Change Confirmation")
        If response = vbYes Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            'Reject the change
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            currentCell = lastVal
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If

'Checks for task column. If timestamp cell at current row is empty
'and something was entered into task column, fills timestamp cell
If sCol = taskCol Then
    If Cells(sRow, timeCol) = "" = True Then
        If currentCell <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(sRow, timeCol) = Now()
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sRow, sCol
    Dim currentCell As Range

    sRow = Target.row
    sCol = Target.Column


    Set currentCell = Cells(sRow, sCol)
    lastVal = currentCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a bug in Excel concerning dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722566/is-there-a-bug-in-excel-concerning-dates)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Fictional_leap_day_in_the_year_1900) is a [well-known bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year) that was [intentionally introduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug) by the [original Excel team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722566/is-there-a-bug-in-excel-concerning-dates) to [maintain compatibility](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/10/26/the-leap-year-1900-bug-in-excel/) with [Lotus 1-2-3](https://superuser.com/questions/481496/why-are-excel-weekdays-wrong-for-1900).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

> When Lotus 1-2-3 was first released, the program assumed that the year 1900 was a leap year, even though it actually was not a leap year. This made it easier for the program to handle leap years and caused no harm to almost all date calculations in Lotus 1-2-3.
>
> When Microsoft Multiplan and Microsoft Excel were released, they also assumed that 1900 was a leap year. This assumption allowed Microsoft Multiplan and Microsoft Excel to use the same serial date system used by Lotus 1-2-3 and provide greater compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3. Treating 1900 as a leap year also made it easier for users to move worksheets from one program to the other.
>
> Although it is technically possible to correct this behavior so that current versions of Microsoft Excel do not assume that 1900 is a leap year, the disadvantages of doing so outweigh the advantages.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year

Comment: @jsotola - I think they'll just keep the current universe for backward compatibility reasons.